# Trigger doesn't work as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I'm having a bit of a trouble with my Trigger.
It's supposed to:

- Update a history table on inserts in my primary table and add a timestamp.
- If a row in the history table already has the same values, nothing should be added, but a counter should increase and the time should be updated.
- If it was over 24hours ago since last update, a new row will be created.

**Sloppy pseudocode:**

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( --if the value isn't in the history table
    SELECT History.value1 FROM History, INSERTED
    WHERE History.value1 LIKE INSERTED.value1
    AND History.value2 LIKE INSERTED.value2
       ) 
       OR EXISTS ( --or if it has been added over 24h ago
        SELECT History.value1 FROM History, INSERTED
        WHERE History.value1 LIKE INSERTED.value1
        AND History.value2 LIKE INSERTED.value2
        AND DATEDIFF(HOUR,History.time, GETDATE()) > 24
       )     
    BEGIN --Insert it
        INSERT INTO History(value1, value2, counter, time)
        SELECT value1, value2, counter GETDATE() FROM INSERTED
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN  -- else, increase counter and add new time
        UPDATE History
        SET History.time = GETDATE(), 
                               History.Items = History.Items + INSERTED.Items
        FROM History
        JOIN INSERTED ON History.value1 = INSERTED.value1
        AND History.value2 = INSERTED.value2
            AND DATEDIFF(HOUR, _History.time, GETDATE()) < 24;
    END
```

**example table:**

```
__________________________________________________
| value1 | value2 | counter | time(last updated) |
+------------------------------------------------+
| test1  | test2  |    1    |        < 24h       |
| test3  | test4  |    1    |        > 24h       |
| test3  | test4  |    1    |        < 24h       |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

**input:**

```
INSERT INTO main_table(value1, value2, counter)
VALUES ('test3', 'test4', 1);
```

**resulting table:**

```
__________________________________________________
| value1 | value2 | counter | time(last updated) |
+------------------------------------------------+
| test1  | test2  |    1    |        < 24h       |
| test3  | test4  |    1    |        > 24h       |
| test3  | test4  |    1    |        < 24h       | <--This counter+time should be updated
| test3  | test4  |    1    |        < 24h       | <--This row shouldn't be added
+------------------------------------------------+
```

I Understand WHY this happens (because the code finds a history value thats over 24h, disregarding the newer one(s)) but I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Bearing in mind that `inserted` can contain *multiple* rows, I don't think your `IF`/`ELSE` logic can be correct. What if *some* rows already have history values and some don't? Also, what version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: running on server version: 11.0.2100.60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG I solved it ^^ Been trying to fix it for like 2 hours and just when I post it to stackoverflow I manage to fix it ^^

**What I did:**

Changed the second "EXIST" test from:

```
OR EXISTS ( --or if it has been added over 24h ago
        SELECT History.value1 FROM History, INSERTED
        WHERE History.value1 LIKE INSERTED.value1
        AND History.value2 LIKE INSERTED.value2
        AND DATEDIFF(HOUR,History.time, GETDATE()) > 24
       )
```

to:

```
OR NOT EXISTS ( --or if it has been added over 24h ago
        SELECT History.value1 FROM History, INSERTED
        WHERE NOT History.value1 LIKE INSERTED.value1
        OR History.value2 LIKE INSERTED.value2
        OR DATEDIFF(HOUR,History.time, GETDATE()) > 24
       )
```

Comment: "solved" - have you read and understood my comment? Your trigger is probably still broken.

Comment: Yeah, but I dont think that inserts will be done with multiple rows.

Comment: it's a bad habit to get into to write triggers that are broken for multi-row inserts (updates, deletes). Especially in this case where it won't produce an error message or even a warning if one happens - it will just do the wrong thing.

Comment: Got any suggestions on how to fix it then? Because I shure dont know ^^'

Comment: I've posted my answer (although I have just been polishing it up a bit)

Answer (score 1):

I think your trigger is still broken if `inserted` contains a mixture of rows - since your `IF`/`ELSE` structure makes a single decision on what action to take.

It would be better to have a [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), something like:

```
;MERGE INTO History h USING INSERTED i
   ON h.Value1 = i.Value1 and h.Value2 = i.Value2 and
      DATEDIFF(HOUR,h.time, GETDATE()) <= 24
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET time = GETDATE(), Items = h.Items + i.Items
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (Value1,Value2,Items,time)
   VALUES (i.Value1,i.Value2,i.Items,GETDATE());
```

Which should replace your whole trigger body.

---

Incidentally, `DATEDIFF` counts the number of transitions across boundaries, rather than computing an exact difference (E.g. `DATEDIFF(hour,'00:59','01:01')` is 1). If you want to get closer to a 24 hour cutoff which also considers minutes and seconds, a better comparison would be:

```
h.Time >= DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE())
```

Which incidentally would also allow an index that includes `History`'s `time` column to be used.

Comment: I've tried it the way you posted, but it says "incorrect syntax near ';'" on line 2(ON h.value = i.value.....)

Comment: @Yoan - you have your tables, database, etc. I don't. It makes it a tad difficult to post fully debugged queries.

Answer (score 1):

--Change your criteria statements like this. it will work. Anyway, the trigger you write really not good. Triggers should design to deal with set not records, as one batch insert/update/delete only can trigger once.

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( --if the value isn't in the history table
SELECT History.value1 FROM History, INSERTED
WHERE History.value1 LIKE INSERTED.value1
AND History.value2 LIKE INSERTED.value2
   ) 
   OR EXISTS ( --or if it has been added over 24h ago
    SELECT INSERTED.value1 
    FROM INSERTED
    cross apply
        (select max(History.[time]) mx_time
        from    History
        where   History.value1 LIKE INSERTED.value1
                AND History.value2 LIKE INSERTED.value2
        ) as t
    WHERE DATEDIFF(HOUR,t.mx_time, GETDATE()) >= 24
   )     
BEGIN --Insert it
    INSERT INTO History(value1, value2, items, time)
    SELECT value1, value2, items, GETDATE() FROM INSERTED
END
ELSE
BEGIN  -- else, increase counter and add new time

    UPDATE History
    SET History.time = GETDATE(), 
                           History.Items = History.Items + INSERTED.Items
    FROM History
    JOIN INSERTED ON History.value1 = INSERTED.value1
    AND History.value2 = INSERTED.value2
        AND DATEDIFF(HOUR, History.time, GETDATE()) < 24;
END
```